# Gnome-Shell forgets theme after reboot?

Tags: gnome, 12.10, themes, gnome-shell-extension

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome-Shell from the `gnome-3-team/gnome3` ppa.

This is working great, and I have my custom theme setup.

The only issue I am running into is that Gnome-Shell seems to forget the theme after every reboot.

If I open `gnome-tweak-tool` the correct theme **is** selected, however it is not applied; if I select anything else and then re-select the theme it is then applied correctly.

What could be causing this? It does not seem to be related to a specific theme, as I am getting the issue with both `Mountain Shell` and `Elegance Colours`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick debug of selectively disabling extensions it came down to my initial attempt at *fixing/tweaking* the original gnome-shell theme.

Specifically the installation of the [remove rounded corners extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/448/remove-rounded-corners/).

While toggling this extension I noticed that every time I re-enabled it my shell theme would revert back to default. so un-installing does the trick.